# Programação Orientada a Objeto Duvida simples com Implements

Tags: php, método, parâmetros, biblioteca

Estou usando uma biblioteca do php.

Tem uma classe com um método que recebe como parâmetro exatamente esse texto que vou escrever: `TextElementInterface $pText = null` .Na definição de `TextElementInterface` ele é uma interface.

Como eu passo isso via parâmetro? por exemplo se fosse uma classe era só instanciar atribuir ela a uma variável e passar essa variável por parâmetro no método desejado, mas uma interface eu não sei como faço?

Comment: vc não tem nenhuma classe que implemente essa interface?

Comment: @rray tem esse comentário na biblioteca //Rich text element interface. e Tem uma classe Rich text, porem não venho nela a implementação dessa interface.

Comment: se ela implementasse era só chamar os métodos normais?

Comment: A ideia é exatamente a mesma, o único detalhe é que a classe que você precisa instanciar precisa ser uma implementação desta interface. Qual seria essa classe depende do contexto, do que está fazendo e de qual biblioteca é.

Comment: Se implementar é só passar esse objeto como argumento e pode chamar os métodos normalmente. Lembre que a interface te obriga a implementar alguns métodos. Definir o tipo do parâmetro como uma interface permite flexibilizar a 'entrada'.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss a biblioteca é PHPOFFICE - PHPPresentation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bem, neste caso essa assinatura está obrigando que o valor passado implemente a interface **TextElementInterface**. O exemplo abaixo é bem simples, mas acredito ser adequado para a pergunta:

```
<?php

interface TextElementInterface
{
    public function __construct($pText);
}

class ImplementaInterface implements TextElementInterface
{
    public function __construct($pText) {
        return $pText;
    }
}

class MinhaClasse
{
    public function chamarMetodo(TextElementInterface $pText = null) {
        echo "Opa! Funciona.";
    }
}

$obj = new MinhaClasse;
$obj->chamarMetodo(new ImplementaInterface('Qualquer coisa aqui'));
```

Observe que passei como parâmetro `new ImplementaInterface('Qualquer coisa aqui')`, essa classe está implementado a interface ** TextElementInterface**.

Se tentar algo como: `$obj->chamarMetodo('Qualquer coisa aqui');` verá que ocorre erro pois a interface não está sendo implementada.

Comment: Legal! me ajudou, consegui implementar aqui e funcionou!